# Does putting the graphics into 2D save battery

Tags: fallout-shelter

FS is a very power intensive game. I have often felt my phone get hot when I play it for more than 10 minutes. I have assumed it is because of the number of 3D elements being rendered during gameplay.

When I zoom out of the game enough the graphics turn 2D:

[image: Fallout Shelter 2D]

Does this affect the power consumption of the game? Will the amount of charge in my battery last longer while I have the game like this?

Comment: My guess is that the best way to test this is to leave the game running for say, an hour and check the battery, then switch the zoom and check again. Most likely recharging in between. That *might* give you some idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The battery will last a small amount longer because it's not constantly re-rendering 3D modelling but it's not a considerable amount. This is because the processes that remain active to keep the game running still use up a fair bit of power.

Comment: Processes such as keeping track of where Ds are, training timers, resource timers, etc. Makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: My phone certainly gets considerably hotter in 3D mode than 2D.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced battery problems while playing the game on my iPhone.  I tried following in the directions in this article: [Download Fallout Shelter PC](http://www.alltechfeed.com/download-fallout-shelter-for-pc-laptop/); and started playing on my computer. I hope this works to you as well.